# Why can't PhantomJS open my Web page?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to load [this Web page](https://f8790d1e-aknuds1.node.tutum.io/) from PhantomJS 2 on Ubuntu 15.04, via Python 2/Selenium, but the request simply times out. Why is it unable to open the page?

I've tried the following Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

timeout = 30

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('https://f8790d1e-aknuds1.node.tutum.io/')
```

This eventually times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've edited your script so that it now loads the site and succesfully produces a screenshot.

I think the problem was that you've set a too short timeout. It taken out, site will eventually load. Also you have to account for the misconfigured SSL certificate on the demo.

**Update:** added time measurements. From my geolocation script runs for 13-14 seconds.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# timeout = 10
# driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)

start = time.time()
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=ANY'])
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('https://f8790d1e-aknuds1.node.tutum.io/')
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
driver.quit()

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: The real problem was actually trying to open the page from Selenium, which just times out. I guess that should've been the question.

Comment: Let's have another question then :) but please show the script there.

Comment: Have re-formulated question now.

Comment: How long does it take to load for you? For me it's taking forever with your edited script.

Comment: Actually, it worked for me a couple of times now, but then it's back to hanging indefinitely.

Comment: Adding `'--ssl-protocol=ANY'` might help, as it's working now at least.

Comment: Added time measurements. Script runs for 13-14 seconds, ping to f8790d1e-aknuds1.node.tutum.io is 117ms avg.